# Postal in ASP .Net 5 (Mvc 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, postal

Has anyone successfully used `Postal` in an `Asp.Net 5`? I tried installing `Postal.Mvc5` `Nuget` package in an `MVC 6` project, and although the project compiled it gave runtime errors, specifically the following:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine..ctor(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator, IResolver`1 activatorResolver, IDependencyResolver dependencyResolver, VirtualPathProvider pathProvider)

TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines' threw an exception.
System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.get_Engines()
```

If anyone has managed to get `Postal` working in `MVC 6`, please outline the steps involved in getting it successfully configured, and in particular the `Asp.Net 5` equivalent of the following smtp configuration.

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
        <network host="example.org" port="25" defaultCredentials="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: ASP.NET 5 is rewritten completely, so `System.Web.*` packages are no longer there, that’s why Postal cannot find them. You could maybe add them, but I doubt that ASP.NET 5 can handle them at all. You’re better off waiting for an update (maybe you want to open an issue on the project site), or sticking to MVC5 completely for now.

Comment: Thanks, Poke. I have opened an issue for Asp.Net 5 support. The issue can be found here: https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal/issues/129